# How to restrict a data entry user to work only 8 hours on my website

Tags: asp.net, sql-server, time

I have developed a web application for one of my clients, my client requirement is that.

Every data entry user work in his working area only for 6 Hours not more than that. Otherwise he log out when he try to log in to his working area. I am using Asp.net C# with SQL Server 2005

Any help will be highly appreciated. Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

You need to clarify the requirement:

1- If the user has to create an account online to be able to work,
    and

1-1- he or she works from a specific time to a specific end time,
    and he or she has to be able to come back the next day and work for
    another 6 hours, then you can have two columns in your database for
    start_time and finish_time and reject any request to the database
    from that user that falls outside of that range.

1-2- he or she works every day but at a flexible time, then when the
    user logs in every day, put the timestamp in a column in db called
    start, and check every request to the database by that user to see
    if it's past 6 hours after start time. Reject the request if so
    until next day.

1-3- he or she works ONLY ONCE for 6 hours and does not return to
    work the next day, then simply have an account_created column and
    disable the account after 6 hours using a flag in the database.
    Check every request to the database to see if the user is disabled
    or not.

2- If the user does not have to create an account and can only work
    for 6 hours and

2-1- works at fixed hours, then reject any request from his/her
    workstation outside of the specified hours. If you are lucky and
    each workstation has a specific IP address, then
    Request.UserHostAddress gives you and idea of what workstation has
    been interacting with your code.

2-2 works at flexible hours, use the same method of 2-1 but have a
    start column in your database and check to see if the user (specific
    IP) is interacting with your code within 6 hours of the start time.

If you have to use login/logout as you said, do the above and instead of rejecting the user outright, just log them off by clearing the session cookie. If they want to log back in, check to see if they are within the acceptable time limit, if not, immediately log them off.

Comment: Thanks for your king response:

Comment: Thanks for your kind response: my client requirement is :every day a user must work only 6 hours not more than that. the time may be any time in day.??do you have any code .a lot of thanks

Comment: I don't have any code but as I said it's not hard to write only the 6 hour limitation part of it. Just keep track of when the user first logs in every day, set the session cookie to expire 6 hours later, have a session variable that has the expiration time in it, at the beginning of each asp.net code check the current time against the session variable for expiration and if it's passed that, log the user off by removing all session variables and removing the cookie. The start time everyday needs to go in the database, the expiration can be calculated within your program.

Answer (score 0):

This could get tricky.

You're going to have to **save the login time in a database**.
Then, as part of the login routine, you check that login time.

Where it gets complicated is that a user might log in several times during the day. If nobody works through midnight, you can query for the min login time for today's date for this user.

But what if a user logs in at, say 9:00 am, then logs out at 12:00 for lunch, and logs back in at 1:00. If you check min time for today's date at 3:00, you will be ignoring the lunch break, and you won't be letting the user log back in.

In the end, the individual logical steps are simple. But you do need to think about all of the different scenarios.

Comment: Yes alot of Thanks:this is the solution can u have some code  in C# for situation like this ??